# Как создать unit файл для автозапуска бота

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

Нашел скрипт, который перезапускает бота в случае падения. Но я не понимаю что нужно указывать в `WorkingDirectory` и `ExecStart`. Директорий с ботом находится в учетной записи "my-bot", путь к исполняющему файлу `main.py`: /home/my-bot/bot/main.py. Файл `bot.service` с этим скриптом нужно положить в /etc/systemd/system, но под какой учетной записью? root или my-bot ? или это не имеет значения?
Я новичок в ubuntu, поэтому буду рад руководству, как сделать скрипт для перезапуска бота.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Bot
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=
ExecStart=
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `WorkingDirectory` можно не указывать, если Ваш сервис не работает с файлами (или работает, но при этом использует абсолютные пути).
- `ExecStart` - это команда, которую Вы вводите в командной строке, чтобы запустить бота (нужно указывать полные пути)
- `User` - это имя пользователя в системе, от имени которого Вы хотите запустить бота. От этого зависит какие пермиссии будут у бота, а каких не будет. Например некоторый файл, может быть доступен для чтения только пользователю `А`. Это, значит, что бот, запущенный от имени пользователя `Б` упадет при попытке обратиться к файлу. Хорошим стилем является подготовка отдельного пользователя для запуска сервисов (с минимальным необходимым набором привилегий). Если Вы будете запускать сервис из под рута, Ваш бот может напортачить в системе.

Подробнее по ключам можно [почитать тут](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#).

Comment: Бот работает с sqlite3, и иногда при вызове определенной команды пользователем, создает и сразу удаляет файл внутри своей директории, да и вообще все процессы внутри своей директории. Можно оставить WorkingDirectory пустой? Или вообще убрать?

Comment: Лучше указать папку, где такие файлы будут создаваться. Можно указать папку в которой он находится, можно выделить какую-то другую.