# Автозагрузка в ubuntu

Tags: автозагрузка

Я написал программу с расширением .out
Как я могу ее добавить в автозагрузку при помощи консоли?

Comment: У Вас есть два "варианта" - программа стартует при старте системы (нормально для всяких демонов и серверов) и второе - UI приложение, которое должно быть запущено, когда пользователь уже залогинился.

Comment: Автозагрузку после чего (загрузки системы, загрузки экранного менеджера, входа пользователя, подключения сети)? И от имени какого пользователя? Один раз для всей системы или индивидуально для каждого пользователя?

Comment: У меня выделенный сервер VPS, когда я его перезагружаю нужно чтоб стартовала программа под пользователем root. Я просто в линуксе нуб)
Программа открывает нужный порт и слушает его, отвечает на команды.

Comment: Тогда напишите и включите соответствующую systemd-службу

Comment: 99%, что Вам нужен systemd скрипт. пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175822/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-unit-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0

Comment: Собственно, про сервер и про systemd ответ уже давно есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/968702

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автозапуск программы при старте сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968702/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: Я создал сервис, он запускается. Но приложение по прежнему не отвечает. Как будто прав нет...
Содержимое сервиса:
[Unit]
Description=MyProject service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root/MyProject
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/root/MyProject/HttpServer.out
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
Environment="PATH=/root/MyProject"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Все подробности надо внести в вопрос. Дальше - информацию о статусе (`systemctl status`) вашего сервиса. Судя по названию исполняемого файла, у вас какой-то http сервер, значит надо посмотреть через `netstat -lt`, открыт ли слушающий сокет.